# Insert values into database and return them into interactive grid (APEX 5.1)

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a **Form** with **Select list** item ***P2_PERSON*** (it's type is **Shared component** and it shows names of people that are in the **PERSON** table in database), two **Date pickers** ***P2_DATEFROM*** and ***P2_DATETO*** and one **hot button** labelled **GO**. Below, on the same page (see picture 1) is **Interactive Grid** (a new region in apex 5.1, looks like a fresh and powerful feature). What I need to do, and can't find the answer anywhere is: after the person is selected in **Select list** labeled *Osoba*, what can be seen in the first picture, and two dates are chosen from two **Date pickers**, clicking the **GO** button 5 rows are inserted in table ***CONTROL_TT*** and presented on ***Interactive grid*** on the page. Difference between dates must not be larger than seven days to avoid too many inserts in the table.

> Each *day* in the range of dates entered represents one new inserted
>   row in ***CONTROL_TT*** table and that date is stored in **date**
>   column of every row.
>
> Also, ***person_id*** collected (or   passed) from ***P2_PERSON***
>   **Select list** Item is stored in **person_id** column of ***CONTROL_TT*** table. Columns of ***CONTROL_TT*** table are
>
> **(control_id, person_id, date, time_from, time_to, hours_total, project_id, status, desc, person_id_accept_req)**
>
> **Id** column is populated trough sequence **seq_evidencija**

**time_from**, **time_to**, **hours_total** and **desc** are inserted/tiped (inputed) manually by the user when the **interactive Grid** is populated with data. **project_id** will be **Select list** (from table **Project** in db) on **Interactive grid** and **status** is the same as **project_id** using **Status** table as reference for data. Tnx

---

[Web page in browser look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCOus.png)

[Look from apex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Buq.png)

Comment: Please provide examples to help clarify your question. And use proper line breaks and formatting.

Comment: I will correct my question when I get home. I wrote it on mobile phone because I'm traveling. Thanks for help. Will edit it asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your **GO** button must have **Action: Submit Page**.
2. Create validation **Type: PL/SQL Expression** having this code:

   `to_date(:P2_DATETO, 'dd-mon-yyyy')-to_date(:P2_DATEFROM, 'dd-mon-yyyy') <=7`

(note, please modify the date format if needed) with condition **When Button Press: GO** and some message that you want to display.
3. Create a process that runs on condition **When Button Press: GO** with this PL/SQL Code:

```
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN 1..(To_date(:P2_DATETO, 'dd-mon-yyyy')-To_date(:P2_DATEFROM, 'dd-mon-yyyy')) 
    LOOP 
        INSERT INTO control_tt (person_id, DATE) 
        VALUES (:P2_PERSON, To_date(:P2_DATETO, 'dd-mon-yyyy') + i - 1); 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to solve the problem thanks to your help. FOR LOOP did the trick and I haven't got to loops yet. So the part of code `VALUES (:P2_PERSON, To_date(:P2_DATETO, 'dd-mon-yyyy') + i - 1);` is because `i` has the value of 1 and when `i - 1` happens in the first run the initial value is set to 0, that is, the first day of the specified (inputed) date.